# Can I explicitly check for cancellation / terminate async computation?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have an async computation like the following (see inline comments):

```
async {
  //...
  do! Async.Sleep(100) //cancellation may happen during sleep
  //... but isn't checked at the end of the sleep, so regular, non-async computations are executed here 
}
```

In order to force a cancellation check / terminate the entire async computation before the "regular" computation part is reached, I insert an effective no-op `do! Async.Sleep(1)` immediately after the `do! Async.Sleep(100)`. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Possibly even something like `do! Async.Nop`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
let nop = async.Return ()
```

Then you could use it like:

```
async {
    // ...
    do! Async.Sleep 100
    do! nop
}
```