# Running Async computations with timeout

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I don't understand the semantics of `Async.RunSynchronously` when given a *timeout* argument. Why doesn't the following example terminate?

```
let runInMaxTime (time: int) (work: Async<'T>) =
    try
        Async.RunSynchronously(work,time)
        |> Some
    with
    | _     ->
        None

let rec forever () : unit  = 
    printfn "Forever looping"
    forever ()

// Never terminates
let x = runInMaxTime 10 <| async {return forever ()}
```

What would a proper implementation of `runInMaxTime` look like? The only thing I've come up with that works is based on `Task`s and *cancellation tokens*.

Answer (score 6):

The timeout and cancellation token cannot arbitrarily stop an async computation, they can only do so when the computation yields, by using `let!`, `do!` etc. Your example computation doesn't do that.

This would work as you expect.

```
let rec forever () : Async<unit> =
    async {
        printfn "Forever looping"
        return! forever()
    }

let x = runInMaxTime 1000 <| forever()
```

Comment: @esevelos If you have a long-running `async` computation, you could create a `nop` function and call it at convenient cancellation points in your code, e.g., [Can I explicitly check for cancellation / terminate async computation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676657/can-i-explicitly-check-for-cancellation-terminate-async-computation/18677531#18677531)